# How do I find the domain of $f(x)=(x+1)/(x^2+x+3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I know that the quadratic equation must be greater than 0. But the critical nos. are complex. What do I do?

Comment: The quadratic *expression* (not equation) in the denominator doesn't need to be *greater* than zero (you can perfectly well divide by negative numbers). It needs to be *nonzero*. And the fact that the roots (not critical numbers) are complex means this quadratic expression is never zero, at least when $x$ is a real number. So there are no problems, and the domain is all real numbers.

Comment: Hint: the fact that it has complex roots tells you that the function $x \rightarrow x^2+x+3$ is either always positive or always negative. What do you think you can infer from that?

Comment: @symplectomorphic Oh, right. Thanks for that!

Comment: @user303287: you're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

The expression $\frac{x+1}{x^2+x+3}$ is defined if and only if $x^2+x+3\neq 0$.

Therefore, since all roots of $x^2+x+3$ are *complex*, you know that for all real numbers $x$, the expression is defined and so all real numbers are in the domain of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Think of $x^2+x+3$ as $(x+1/2)^2+11/4$, as it is the sum of two positive numbers it is always greater than $0$.